# React native picker changes redux store state after several selects

Tags: react-native, react-redux

I have two `<Picker />` in a component that both are connected to the redux store, one changes the redux state sucessfully everytime, the second one that controls the theme of the application works one time then I have to click several times to change the state, seems that the second picker doesn't always trigger `onValueChange()`

`Settings.js`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Cell, Section, TableView } from 'react-native-tableview-simple';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { View, Text, ScrollView, Picker, StyleSheet, Switch } from 'react-native';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  settingsBanner: {
    backgroundColor: '#27ae60',
    padding: '20%',
  },
  settingsBannerHeading: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontSize: 50,
    color: 'white',
  },
  settingsBannerSubheading: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: 'white',
  },
});

const Settings = ({ currentLanguage, currentTheme, changeLanguage, changeTheme }) => (
  <ScrollView style={{ backgroundColor: '#EFEFF4' }}>
    {/* TODO: Make banner change color based on current selected theme. */}
    {/* TODO: Remove inline styling that is too long. */}
    <View style={{ backgroundColor: currentTheme === 'two' ? '#000' : '#27ae60', padding: '20%' }}>
      <Text style={styles.settingsBannerHeading}>Test</Text>
      <Text style={styles.settingsBannerSubheading}>Settings</Text>
    </View>
    <TableView>
      <Section header="GENERAL">
        <Cell
          contentContainerStyle={{ paddingRight: 0 }}
          title="Language"
          cellAccessoryView={
            <Picker
              mode="dropdown"
              onValueChange={itemValue => changeLanguage(itemValue)}
              selectedValue={currentLanguage}
              style={{ width: '32%' }}
            >
              <Picker.Item key="1" label="English" value="en" />
              <Picker.Item key="2" label="Español" value="es" />
            </Picker>
          }
        />
      </Section>
      <Section header="PERSONALIZATION">
        <Cell
          title="Theme"
          contentContainerStyle={{ paddingRight: 0 }}
          subtitleColor="#9E9E9E"
          cellStyle="Subtitle"
          detail="Change the application theme"
          cellAccessoryView={
            <Picker
              mode="dropdown"
              onValueChange={itemValue => changeTheme(itemValue)}
              selectedValue={currentTheme}
              style={{ width: '32%' }}
            >
              <Picker.Item key="1" label="Default" value="one" />
              <Picker.Item key="2" label="AMOLED" value="two" />
            </Picker>
          }
        />
      </Section>
      <Section header="PRIVACY">
        <Cell
          title="Obscure"
          subtitleColor="#9E9E9E"
          cellStyle="Subtitle"
          detail="Hide the content of the app when changing application"
          cellAccessoryView={<Switch />}
        />
      </Section>
    </TableView>
    <Text>{currentTheme}</Text>
    <Text>{currentLanguage}</Text>
  </ScrollView>
);

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    currentTheme: state.configuration.currentTheme,
    currentLanguage: state.configuration.currentLanguage,
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    changeTheme: (theme) => {
      dispatch({
        type: 'CHANGE_CURRENT_THEME',
        payload: theme,
      });
    },
    changeLanguage: (language) => {
      dispatch({
        type: 'CHANGE_CURRENT_LANGUAGE',
        payload: language,
      });
    },
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Settings);
```

`configurationReducer.js`

```
const initialState = {
  currentLanguage: 'en',
  obscure: false,
  currentTheme: 'one',
};

const configurationReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'CHANGE_CURRENT_LANGUAGE':
      state = {
        ...state,
        currentLanguage: action.payload,
      };

      return state;
    case 'CHANGE_CURRENT_THEME':
      state = {
        ...state,
        currentTheme: action.payload,
      };

      return state;
    case 'ACTIVATE_OBSCURE':
      state = {
        ...state,
        obscure: true,
      };

      return state;
    case 'DEACTIVATE_OBSCURE':
      state = {
        ...state,
        obscure: false,
      };

      return state;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default configurationReducer;
```

Comment: You've got it set as a `dropdown`. Is it possible that the second picker is trying to render outside of a parent `View` that is somehow not receiving the touch event? If there's another element below, it will automatically have a higher `zIndex`, which would potentially receive the touch event before the dropdown.

Comment: Has a very strange pattern, when I select it for the first time it changes the state, then if I try to select the second option is changes the picker selectValue but not the state, to make it change the state I have to select the first option then the second one then it changes the state.